# Display return data from external javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm trying to display the return data from the external `Javascript`.

Here's my code

**global-functions.js**

```
function CurrentDate() {
var url = CurrentDateUrl();
$.get(url, function (e) {
    var Date = e.toString();
    console.log(e);
    console.log(Date);
    return Date;
});
// RETURN the Current Date example. 11/29/2013 10:57:56 AM
}
```

**Sample.cshtml (View)**

```
<h2>Transaction Date: <b><span id="TransactionYear"></span></b></h2>

<script>
function CurrentDateUrl(){
    return '@Url.Action("CurrentDate", "Global")';
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    var Date = CurrentDate();

    document.getElementById("TransactionYear").innerHTML = Date; // the return is UNDEFINED

});
</script>
```

As we can see in `global-functions.js` there is no problem as it return from what i wanted but when I try to call the function `CurrentDate()` it will return to **UNDEFINED** . Any other way to display it? or other good approach?

**EDIT :**

*Question : Can you verify that function CurrentDate() is called?*

- Yes. As I try to return the hard coded string in `CurrentDate()` it will display.

I tried the suggested answer below

```
function CurrentDate() {
var url = CurrentDateUrl();
var result;
$.get(url, function (e) {
    var date= e.toString();
    console.log(e); // will return the Date in console
    console.log(date); // will return the Date in console
    result = date;
    console.log(result); // will return the Date in console
});
console.log(result); // will return UNDEFINED in console
return "Sample";

}
```

**OUTPUT**

Transaction Date : Sample

Comment: @Shiven What do you mean by linked? If calling the javascript is what you mean then I already called it. the `return data` is **Undefined** and not the function

Comment: shiven means did you included your global-functions.js in html view, and that too after script tag where you defined function ?

Comment: You are also redefining the Javascript keyword `Date()` with your variable name. I'd choose something else: at least `date = ` rather than `Date = `

Comment: @shyammakwana.me Yes, I included the `global-functions.js` in my shared `_Layout.cshtml` cause I also used it in my other views

Comment: Can you verify that function CurrentDate() is called?

Comment: Maybe you linked script correctly but you have issue to return data from CurrentDate() function? Problem can be happen because $.get() doesn't return data. It will execute callback.

Comment: Have you checked the Console for errors?

Comment: @KScandrett Yes I did :)

Comment: @kat1330 I will return normaly if its a normal string as I stated in my edit but if i try to return the date it wont

Comment: @FrostyPinky Thanks for update. I missed one thing and I provided some adjustments. Reason why you returned UNDEFINED in console.log(result) is probably because is ASYNC call. Use with synchronous call and try to return result and share how it looks?

Comment: @kat1330 Thank you. I didn't think about ASYNC. It works now

Comment: @FrostyPinky I updated with async call. You can try it async too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using $.get() function in wrong way! Please see following [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for more info. It cannot return value, it should execute callback function when request is finished!

You should pass function as callback in $.get() (which you are doing) and in that function do logic which you want (which you are NOT doing right now.)

I will rather do like this (probably not good in your case because you are using external file):

```
$.get(url, function (e) {
    var Date = e.toString();
    console.log(e);
    console.log(Date);

    document.getElementById("TransactionYear").innerHTML = Date
});
```

Or try this in your case (synchronous call):

```
 function CurrentDate() {
    var url = CurrentDateUrl();
    var result;

    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        result = data;
    } 
 });
 return result;
}
```

Please note: I am using  $.ajax() and I am not returning any value inside $.ajax. Also I added **async: false**. Now you can return result in that way but it is **not async**.

If you want to use asynchronous request you have to use callback function. Some implementation can be like in following example:

```
  function CurrentDate(callbackFunction) {
    var url = CurrentDateUrl();
    var result;

    $.get(url, function (e) {
        var Date = e.toString();
        callbackFunction(Date);
    });
}

// Call your function in code like this
CurrentDate(function(result) {
    // handle your result here
});
```

Comment: This is not the answer which solves OP's question. He's getting undefined error.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me How we can expect value from this line: var Date = CurrentDate(); $.get() doesn't return value?